# Gmail calendar invites to an outlook email goes directly to the recipient Gmail calendar instead of outlook

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I have an hotmail/outlook email. When people send me invites from their Google calendar to my hotmail email, I receive them my Google calendar directly instead of receiving them to my outlook email.

I have read that if my google account use my hotmail email as an alias, the invites from gmail goes directly to my google calendar.

Is it possible to disable this behavior without having to remove my hotmail email from my google account alias?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to disable this behavior without having to remove my hotmail email from my google account alias?

I'm afraid that you need to remove your Gmail account from Alias in order to use Gmail independently to send and receive emails.